# How to list subscriptions by topic for multiple topics?

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to get the Subscription Arn for All of my SNS topics. I have used `list_subscriptions_by_topic` this will return the subscription of a Topic but I have to provide a Topic Arn. However I am looking to return results for multiple topics not just one topic.

Any suggestions?

My current sample:

```py
import credentials
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.list_topics()
response1 = client.list_subscriptions_by_topic(TopicArn=topic['TopicArn'])
print(response1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my codes that will print all the subscription arns of all topics.

```
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns')

topics = sns.list_topics().get('Topics')

for topic in topics:
    subscriptions = sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic(TopicArn=topic.get('TopicArn')).get('Subscriptions')
    for subscription in subscriptions:
        print(subscription.get('SubscriptionArn'))
```